# Azure: Cannot find reference assembly 'Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll'

Tags: azure

The web app runs fine under IIS Express, but when published to Azure through VS 2017 the following error results:

InvalidOperationException: Cannot find reference assembly 'Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll' file for package Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.Reference

```
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.Resolution.ReferenceAssemblyPathResolver.TryResolveAssemblyPaths(CompilationLibrary library, List<string> assemblies)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.Resolution.CompositeCompilationAssemblyResolver.TryResolveAssemblyPaths(CompilationLibrary library, List<string> assemblies)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths(ICompilationAssemblyResolver resolver, List<string> assemblies)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.AssemblyPart+<>c.<GetReferencePaths>b__8_0(CompilationLibrary library)
System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManyIterator<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>> selector)+MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.MetadataReferenceFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable<ApplicationPart> parts, MetadataReferenceFeature feature)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature<TFeature>(TFeature feature)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorReferenceManager.GetCompilationReferences()
System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore<T>(ref T target, ref bool initialized, ref object syncLock, Func<T> valueFactory)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorReferenceManager.get_CompilationReferences()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.LazyMetadataReferenceFeature.get_References()
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.CompilationTagHelperFeature.GetDescriptors()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorTagHelperBinderPhase.ExecuteCore(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorEnginePhaseBase.Execute(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorEngine.Process(RazorCodeDocument document)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorProjectEngine.ProcessCore(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorProjectEngine.Process(RazorProjectItem projectItem)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(string relativePath)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.OnCacheMiss(string normalizedPath)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider.CreateFactory(string relativePath)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.CreateCacheResult(HashSet<IChangeToken> expirationTokens, string relativePath, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.OnCacheMiss(ViewLocationExpanderContext expanderContext, ViewLocationCacheKey cacheKey)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.LocatePageFromViewLocations(ActionContext actionContext, string pageName, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.FindPage(ActionContext context, string pageName)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.GetLayoutPage(ViewContext context, string executingFilePath, string layoutPath)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderLayoutAsync(ViewContext context, ViewBufferTextWriter bodyWriter)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync<TFilter, TFilterAsync>()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

The website is an MVC core 2.1 app targets .Net 4.6.1. Until yesterday this published and hosted successfully but now publishing causes this error during initialisation. Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll is being copied into the publish directory on Azure.

Comment: The same here: MVC Core 2.1 targeting .NET 4.6.1 works in VS2017. If I open and run the solution in VS2019, I get exactly the above exception.